# Hadoop: precomputing data

Tags: hadoop, video-processing, face-recognition

I'm designing a prototype using **Hadoop** for video processing to do face recognition. I thought of 2 ways of doing it.

**Approach 1:**

I was thinking of doing something in 2 steps:

1. A map that receives frames and if a face is found it gets stored for the next step.
2. A map that receives the frames from step 1 (all frames containing 1 face at least) and does face recognition.

Step 1 would be ran only once while step 2 runs every time I want recognize a new face.

---

**Approach 2:**

The other approach I thought about is to do face recognition to all the data every time

The first approach saves time because I don't have to process faceless frames every time I want to do face recognition, it also uses more disk space (and it could be a lot of space).

---

I'm not sure whats better. Is it a bad thing to leave that precomputed frames there forever?